# Is it possible to reference external assembly with native dependencies in Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm getting following exception when doing aforementioned:

> 2017-12-10T12:40:39.771 Exception during runtime resolution of assembly 'Affdex, Version=3.4.1.1320, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null':
>
> 'System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Affdex, Version=3.4.1.1320, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
>       or one of its dependencies. Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131019)
>
> File name: 'Affdex, Version=3.4.1.1320, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups

Is there a location that Azure Function runtime looks for dependencies (like Sys32/Inetsrv in Windows)?